# I get the "Welcome to nginx!" page when I access EC2 public address even though EC2 instance logged "Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:80"

Tags: docker, nginx, amazon-ec2, fastapi, uvicorn

So I'm running a FastAPI project on docker on AWS EC2.

The console on EC2 logged "Uvicorn running on [http://0.0.0.0:80"](http://0.0.0.0:80%22) and before (I fixed) I got some error messages from my main.py file, so I can be sure it actually read my main.py file.
But when I'm trying to reach the public IP address of the server, or the localhost from inside EC2, I get the standard "Welcome to nginx!" page.

On my local machine everything works fine.

What could I check?

Edit: Yeah, I assume I have to write something in the nginx config file to run it behind nginx. Is there a straight-forward way to know what?

Edit: Since the config with nginx is kinda hard, I just deactivated ngnix and I'm running uvicorn inside docker without nginx. On the ec2 machine I can access 'localhost' and can use the api's from my backend.
But it doesn't work from my local laptop. I already checked security group settings in aws.

Edit: 'sudo ufw status' returns 'inactive'

Comment: What container image did you use?

Comment: You're already running nginx on port 80 when uvicorn starts up. uvicorn never actually gets the interface you're using bound to port 80, since nginx already holds that port on that interface. Either disable nginx or use another port for uvicorn (or run uvicorn _behind nginx_ which is the regular setup).

Comment: Yeah, I assume I have to write something in the nginx config file to run it behind nginx. Is there a straight-forward way to know what?

Comment: Since the config with nginx is kinda hard, I just deactivated ngnix and I'm running uvicorn inside docker without nginx. On the ec2 machine I can access 'localhost' and can use the api's from my backend. But it doesn't work from my local laptop. I already checked security group settings in aws.

Answer (score 0):

It worked running uvicorn without nginx after 'sudo ufw disable'. Which is weird because 'sudo ufw status' returned 'inactive' even before the command.